# Actions and effect axioms

Tags: artificial-intelligence, predicate

I want to create an axiom-action tha will enable an agent to move up or down between 
doors if the robot is in a lift node,
and if a route connects the two lift nodes

[image]

> A map which shows the structure of the
>   building. Each node either represent a
>   room (Rn) or a lift (Ln). The robot
>   can either move between rooms (solid
>   lines), or move between  oors (dashed
>   lines). The robots needs to specify
>   the direction (up/down) when taking
>   the lift.

**I was thinking of something like**:

isRobot(r) and isEdge(e) and isLift(x) and isLift(y) and isFloor(Floor1) and isFloor(Floor2) and -(x==y) and -(Floor1==Floor2) and at(inside(r,x),Floor1) and edgeFrom(e,x,y)ad=>goUp(inside(r,y),Floor2) or goDown(inside(r,y),Floor2)

**My predicates are**:
move(x,y)-
edgeFrom(x,y,z)-
at(x,y)
inside(x,y)- 
dusting(x,y)-
isClean(x)-
isRoom(x)-
isEdge(x)-
isFloor(x)-
goUp(x,y)-
goDown(x,y)
isLift(x)
isRobot(x)

Did I formalized the action right?If not what should I do?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: done...it is an exercise from a set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the PDDL and STRIPS documentations; it'll help.

http://planning.cis.strath.ac.uk/competition/

They have sample problems; so you should be able to go along.

All the best.